# std::string to std::chrono time_point

Tags: c++, c++11, casting, c++-chrono

I have a string in the following time format:

`"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"`

where the %f is millisec, eg : `14:31:23.946571`

I want this as a `chrono time_point`. Is there a cast to do this?

Comment: Personally I would use the date algorithms here: http://home.roadrunner.com/~hinnant/date_algorithms.html Specifically `days_from_civil`, and then add on H:M:S. You'll have to decide if that is in the UTC timezone or not, and add a timezone offset if it isn't.

Comment: H:M:S is not the issue. Millisec is really the issue. Otherwise I would have just converted it to a time_t

Comment: @HowardHinnant how would you convert today an ISO 8061 date string (incl. miliseconds) to an manipulative data type using your date.h?

Comment: @BrunoBieri:  Using [my library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) I would `in >> date::parse("%F %T", tp);` where `tp` is a `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point`, or a `time_point<system_clock>`-based time point with precision milliseconds or finer.  One could also use the more verbose string: `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"` which is equivalent.  Often ISO 8061 formats require a `T` separator between the date and time instead of a space, and if you want that, just put the `T` in the format string.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no cast from `std::string` to `std::chrono::time_point`.  You have to build up the `std::chrono::time_point` object.

- Use everything but the microseconds to construct a `std::tm` object (`<ctime>`).
  The year should be based at 1900, not 0.  The month should be based at 0, not 1.
- Use `std::mktime()` to create an `std::time_t` object.
- Create a `std::chrono::time_point` using `from_time_t()`.
- Add the remaining decimal portion (treated as an `int`) as a `std::chrono::microsecond()` duration to your `time_point`.

Be aware that the `<iomanip>` functions `std::ctime()` and `std::put_time()` do not know about precision lower than a second. If you to print that level of precision, you'll need to write a function to do so.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

struct Tm : std::tm {
  int tm_usecs; // [0, 999999] micros after the sec

  Tm(const int year, const int month, const int mday, const int hour,
     const int min, const int sec, const int usecs, const int isDST = -1)
      : tm_usecs{usecs} {
    tm_year = year - 1900; // [0, 60] since 1900
    tm_mon = month - 1;    // [0, 11] since Jan
    tm_mday = mday;        // [1, 31]
    tm_hour = hour;        // [0, 23] since midnight
    tm_min = min;          // [0, 59] after the hour
    tm_sec = sec;          // [0, 60] after the min
                           //         allows for 1 positive leap second
    tm_isdst = isDST;      // [-1...] -1 for unknown, 0 for not DST,
                           //         any positive value if DST.
  }

  template <typename Clock_t = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock,
            typename MicroSecond_t = std::chrono::microseconds>
  auto to_time_point() -> typename Clock_t::time_point {
    auto time_c = mktime(this);
    return Clock_t::from_time_t(time_c) + MicroSecond_t{tm_usecs};
  }
};

int main() {
  using namespace std::chrono;

  auto tp_nomicro = Tm(2014, 8, 19, 14, 31, 23, 0).to_time_point();
  auto tp_micro = Tm(2014, 8, 19, 14, 31, 23, 946571).to_time_point();
  std::cout << duration_cast<microseconds>(tp_micro - tp_nomicro).count()
            << " microseconds apart.\n";

  auto time_c = high_resolution_clock::to_time_t(tp_micro);
  std::cout << std::ctime(&time_c) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. I did notice however that LLVM does not have a from_time_t on the high_resolution_clock

Comment: @bge0: The standard specifies `to_time_t` and `from_time_t` only for `system_clock`.  `high_resolution_clock` is permitted (but not required) to be a type alias for `system_clock`.